# Complexity Theory Consequences of $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{QP}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I have a certain impossibility result that holds unless $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{QP}$. It seems quite likely that one could strengthen this to hold unless $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{P}$, which I would not need to motivate further in my paper.

Unfortunately, I don't have time to do that in this particular paper, so instead want to quickly motivate to cryptographers why $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{QP}$ is unlikely. I know of basic consequences (namely that it would badly violate essentially any form of ETH, so would imply that [tournament dominating set is in P](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38473/implication-of-exponential-time-hypothesis-falseness)), but not much else.

Of course, there's also the obvious motivation that $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{QP}$ implies $\mathsf{NP}\cap\mathsf{coNP}\subseteq \mathsf{QP}$. Most hardness assumptions used in crypto are in $\mathsf{NP}\cap\mathsf{coNP}$, and a particular weak hardness assumption (fixed characteristic finite field discrete log) is known to be in $\mathsf{QP}$. One can therefore interpret $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{QP}$ as "most hardness assumptions in crypto are roughly comperable to fixed characteristic finite-field discrete log", which may work fine as motivation.

Still, is there any clearer motivation from a complexity theory point of view? For example a hierarchy collapse/something along those lines.

Comment: Violates ETH. Related: no known NP-complete problems are known to have subexp time complexity.

Comment: If QP is quasipolynomial time, then it is unequal to NP *unconditionally*: QP is closed under quasipolynomial-time reductions, whereas by a padding argument, the closure of NP under quasipolynomial-time reductions is NQP (nondeterministic quasipolynomial time), which is different from NP by the nondeterministic time-hierarchy theorem.

Comment: See also https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21571 for a related question about the inclusion $\mathrm{NP\subseteq QP}$ (without any exciting answers, I would say).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think that argument + the reference to the $\mathsf{NP}\subseteq \mathsf{QP}$ question is likely a definitive answer to this question. If you want to write it up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I have work on the problem P vs NP, I would like to discuss it, if interested answer this message.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can prove $\mathrm{NP\ne QP}$ unconditionally: $\mathrm{QP}$ is closed under quasipolynomial-time reductions, whereas $\mathrm{NP}$ is not (a simple padding argument shows that the closure of $\mathrm{NP}$ under quasipolynomial-time reductions includes all languages computable in nondeterministic quasipolynomial time, and this class strictly contains $\mathrm{NP}$ by the nondeterministic time-hierarchy theorem).

As for consequences of the weaker assumption $\mathrm{NP\subseteq QP}$, see the question [Is NP in $DTIME(n^{poly\log n})$?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21571/is-np-in-dtimenpoly-log-n).